# Joining predicates with logical && in filter function

Tags: haskell

I just stumbled upon this sentence at [learnyouahaskell.com](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions):

> The filter equivalent of applying several predicates in a list comprehension is either filtering something several times or joining the predicates with the logical && function.

Could someone give an example for the last part (*joining the predicates with the logical && function*)?

Does the author mean something like this (which doesn't work):

```hs
filter ((>3) && (<10)) [5,3]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`filter`'s predicate argument is a function, so you would need to use a lambda:

```
filter (\x -> x > 3 && x < 10) [5,3]
```

I suppose the author was assuming the reader would do the appropriate expansion.

It's also possible to lift boolean operators to operate on predicates using the `(a ->)` `Applicative` instance:

```
filter (liftA2 (&&) (> 3) (< 10)) [5,3]
```

But I don't personally find that particularly nice.

Comment: A fun trick I've seen, if you plan to combine many predicates in this way, is to define `(<&&>) = liftA2 (&&)`. Then you can write `filter ((> 3) <&&> (< 10))`, which is pretty readable.

Comment: In PureScript standard library this works out of the box, via the magic of [HeytingAlgebra](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/4.1.1/docs/Data.HeytingAlgebra#t:HeytingAlgebra)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my opinion, the author should not assume the reader to do the appropriate expansion at this point in the book since neither `lambda`s nor `Applicatives` are introduced yet.

Comment: @ChrisGraf You don't need a lambda if you use `let inRange x = x > 3 && x < 10 in filter inRange [5,3]`. This uses the style the book uses just a few lines above the part you quoted.

Comment: @chi good point, can you add this as an additional answer? I think this could be helpful for others stumbling over this question as well.

Comment: @amalloy: It’s identical for functions, but a better general-purpose definition is `a <&&> b = a >>= \ case { True -> b; False -> pure False }` using a `Monad` constraint to avoid running the effects of `b` if `a` returns `False`

Comment: It's debatable whether that's more general purpose. It's great for monads, but obviously doesn't work for applicatives.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, instead of using a lambda abstraction (anonymous function), one can define the wanted filter predicate using `let` or `where`, giving that a name.

```
let inRange x = x > 3 && x < 10
in  filter inRange [5,3]
```

Using a lambda can be more convenient when the predicate is short, as in this case. On the other hand, giving the predicate a name can help make the code more readable, clarifying the intent.